# How to change the name of a column in data and plot the same name?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

How to change the name of a column in data so as to make a graph show the same name?

Suppose I have a dataset as following:

```
df1 <- structure(list(x = c(0.471183049405856, 0.476924489675844, 0.480511629483199, 
                 0.483165434977241, 0.485287417100514, 0.487062988427817, 0.488593906085656, 
                 0.489942333039825, 0.491149151557131, 0.492242744274582, 0.493243651884703, 
                 0.494167237808148, 0.495025305323116, 0.495827126690313, 0.496580124105679, 
                 0.497290335336037, 0.497962741039605, 0.498601500544381, 0.499210125195558, 
                 0.499791608292661, 0.500348522796291, 0.500883093797793, 0.501397257007638, 
                 0.501892706709832, 0.502370934099313, 0.502833258300107, 0.503280851625977, 
                 0.503714760371498, 0.504135922006343, 0.504545179544836, 0.504943293592729, 
                 0.505330952529756, 0.505708781163009, 0.50607734812106, 0.506437172207061, 
                 0.506788727877202, 0.507132449982303, 0.507468737926817, 0.507797959267225, 
                 0.508120452907355, 0.508436531878426, 0.508746485838093, 0.509050583247572, 
                 0.509349073334039, 0.509642187840954, 0.50993014258393, 0.510213138838402, 
                 0.510491364638746, 0.510764995885807, 0.273834909446762, 0.27430295713079, 
                 0.274780478907738, 0.27526788839687, 0.275765630085615, 0.276274182410922, 
                 0.276794061223569, 0.277325823693944, 0.277870072658552, 0.278427461596961, 
                 0.278998700233689, 0.279584560934396, 0.280185885978721, 0.280803595955992, 
                 0.281438699369311, 0.282092303776465, 0.282765628729155, 0.28346002087443, 
                 0.284176971680392, 0.284918138356476, 0.28568536868024, 0.286480730641409, 
                 0.287306548148645, 0.288165444164402, 0.289060393465214, 0.289994787509927, 
                 0.290972514921796, 0.291998062702268, 0.293076640485976, 0.294214336441441, 
                 0.295418325704117, 0.296697148977613, 0.298061085761838, 0.299522664317045, 
                 0.301097373447033, 0.302804680270659, 0.304669527383085, 0.306724609443897, 
                 0.309013974512169, 0.311599001942209, 0.314568936036706, 0.318060925826036, 
                 0.322302253725204, 0.327713178035074, 0.335220732145911, 0.347719151674229), y = c(0.0631808758618277, 0.116313230978261, 0.166054298420543, 
     0.213863313578767, 0.260341108904907, 0.305793767343661, 0.350404195678465, 
     0.394292406846242, 0.437542044996602, 0.480213808904827, 0.522352940136239, 
     0.563993721573303, 0.605162289102524, 0.645878501304046, 0.686157197279789, 
     0.726009048331865, 0.765441140690319, 0.804457395934132, 0.843058730497948, 
     0.881243716581198, 0.919013988740691, 0.956376365407473, 0.993337870248593, 
     1.02990583580977, 1.0660878822819, 1.10189198987241, 1.13732653213367, 
     1.17240030845593, 1.20712256114117, 1.24150298493916, 1.27555172501872, 
     1.30927936560738, 1.34269691188229, 1.37581577738956, 1.40864774708597, 
     1.44120492964204, 1.47349970778161, 1.50554470656429, 1.53735275092455, 
     1.56893678535007, 1.60030981073666, 1.63148486438573, 1.66247495614457, 
     1.69329296712593, 1.72395163153964, 1.75446359077448, 1.7848410682474, 
     1.8150958586184, 1.84524053213198, 1.07309635918813, 1.05201962306167, 
     1.03089887303296, 1.00972768585275, 0.988499623832403, 0.967208256078716, 
     0.945847235644446, 0.924410321163722, 0.902891406199217, 0.881284576836628, 
     0.859584161001189, 0.837784749300155, 0.815881236444593, 0.793868866846453, 
     0.77174327370469, 0.749500499505129, 0.727137026108102, 0.704649802752252, 
     0.682036271047989, 0.659294385074071, 0.636422624021821, 0.61342000719063, 
     0.59028610367589, 0.56702104871127, 0.543625539424986, 0.5201008790278, 
     0.496448891239306, 0.472672485538668, 0.448778135798887, 0.424774000298316, 
     0.40066733291911, 0.376464675329113, 0.352171857332469, 0.327794037542291, 
     0.30333569057763, 0.278800551192264, 0.254191496951771, 0.229510344594065, 
     0.204757456175833, 0.179931070647805, 0.155026038534016, 0.130031321649085, 
     0.104924533447283, 0.079658124510179, 0.0541151777408059, 0.0279744176895651), Standard.deviation = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("...of the time effect", 
                                                                            "...of the error term"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(1L, 
                                                                                                                                       2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
                                                                                                                                       16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 
                                                                                                                                       29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 
                                                                                                                                       42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 4051L, 4052L, 4053L, 
                                                                                                                                       4054L, 4055L, 4056L, 4057L, 4058L, 4059L, 4060L, 4061L, 4062L, 
                                                                                                                                       4063L, 4064L, 4065L, 4066L, 4067L, 4068L, 4069L, 4070L, 4071L, 
                                                                                                                                       4072L, 4073L, 4074L, 4075L, 4076L, 4077L, 4078L, 4079L, 4080L, 
                                                                                                                                       4081L, 4082L, 4083L, 4084L, 4085L, 4086L, 4087L, 4088L, 4089L, 
                                                                                                                                       4090L, 4091L, 4092L, 4093L, 4094L, 4095L, 4096L), class = "data.frame")
```

Which I plot as:

```
plot <- ggplot(df1, aes(x,y, linetype = Standard.deviation)) + geom_line() + theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold", lineheight=1.5), legend.text=element_text(size=12), legend.position = c(.6, .5), legend.justification = c("right", "center"), legend.box.just = "center", legend.margin = margin(6, 6, 6, 6))
```

Which produces:
[image]

How to remove "." in the "Standard.deviation" sign in the plot?

I know there have to be some easy solution, but altering the dataset as

```
colnames(df1)[3] <- "Standard deviation"
```

Produces erros in the plot.

Comment: Try `+ labs(linetype = "Standard deviation")` instead of changing the column name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@stefan already pointed a great option! Another option could be using `scale_linetype` since your are using the `linetype` to the aesthetic. So you can change the legends name like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
plot <- ggplot(df1, aes(x,y, linetype = Standard.deviation)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_linetype(name = "Standard deviation") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold", lineheight=1.5), 
        legend.text=element_text(size=12), 
        legend.position = c(.6, .5), 
        legend.justification = c("right", "center"), 
        legend.box.just = "center", 
        legend.margin = margin(6, 6, 6, 6))
plot
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>